# jQuery.toggle() doesn't work on table rows in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

Has anyone else had this problem or know of a workaround?  Here's a quick example of a block of code that doesn't work in IE8, but is fine in FF.

HTML:

```
<h1>Toggle Test</h1>
<a onclick="toggleme();">Click here</a>
<table>
    <tr><td>Some visible text</td></tr>
    <tr id="hidden" style="display:none;"><td>Some hidden text</td></tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
function toggleme()
{
    jQuery('#hidden').toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue if you are using jquery-1.3.2. [Here](http://www.code-styling.de/english/jquery-132-causes-problems-at-ie-8) is a solution.